# Problem with WCF custom behavior used in the silverlight client

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

To pass the culture information from client to WCF service, I have created a custom behavior using the custom inspector. The inspector class implements `IDispatchMessageInspector` and the `IClientMessageInspector`.

My client is the silverlight application. And now I'm facing the problem with the `IDispatchMessageInspector` since it's not available in the `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.dll` is not available to add as an assembly reference to Silverlight 4 project.

Can someone help me out ? How to handle the custom behavior to send message from SILVERLIGHT to wcf. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IClientMessageInspector` needs to be implemented and used at the client (silverlight in this case) side whereas `IDispatchMessageInspector` needs to be used at the service side.

Following posts are really helpful:

[Automatic Culture Flowing with WCF by using Custom Behaviour](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/AutomaticCultureFlow.aspx)

[Automate passing valuable information in WCF headers](http://geekswithblogs.net/JanS/archive/2008/03/17/automate-passing-valuable-information-in-wcf-headers.aspx)

[Processing custom WCF header values at server-side](http://geekswithblogs.net/JanS/archive/2008/03/17/processing-custom-wcf-header-values-at-server-side.aspx)